# nativescript paytm plugin giving 404 Not Found Error nginx/1.6.2

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to integrate @nstudio/nativescript-paytm plugin into my app.
as a part the first step i have written code to generate checksum. now i'm getting checksum. if i passed this to further steps as I'm getting below error.

Error in console

```
chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(50)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
06-22 07:31:56.479  2762  2762 I cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(89)] stat /data/user/0/org.nativescript.demo/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
chromium: [ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(62)] mkdir /data/user/0/org.nativescript.demo/cache/WebView/Crashpad: No such file or directory (2)
```

My order param is

```
var order = {
        MID: "V************3",
        ORDER_ID: "order1",
        CUST_ID: "cust123",
        INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail",
        CHANNEL_ID: "WEB",
        TXN_AMOUNT: "100.12",
        WEBSITE: "WEBSTAGING",
        CALLBACK_URL: "https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp",
        CHECKSUMHASH: "NDspZhvSHbq44K3A9Y4daf9En3l2Ndu9fmOdLG+bIwugQ6682Q3JiNprqmhiWAgGUnNcxta3LT2Vtk3EPwDww8o87A8tyn7/jAS2UAS9m+c="
    };
```

I'm using github sample of that plugin(javascript version i.e demo) i haven't modified the code.

Comment: You are suppose to generate a checksum from your own backend implementation of Paytm, it's possible that the one hardcoded in sample code may be expired or no longer valid.

Comment: @Manoj I'm generating fresh checksum every time. i just gave a sample here to confirm that their is no problem with checksum. and from 404 error page if i press back button it alert cancel transaction. so, i'm confused if that page does't exist how cancel transaction alert was coming..!

Comment: @Manoj i also tried this call back url CALLBACK_URL: "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=order1", and Channel id as "WAP". still 404 page error was coming.

Comment: Did you update your Paytm configuration on `paytm/paytm_config.js` file, just making sure.